# How to print mongodb or mongoose query like mysql?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there anything similar in *mongodb*? If we are using dynamic                  variables and print the query then it should print the query with the values in it like shown below.

```
int name = 'john';
int age = 23;

// how we do it in PHP
$query = 'select * from students where name='"name"' and age='"age"';
echo $query;
// result
select * from students where name='john' and age='23';

// how we do it in codeigniter 
echo $this->db->last_query();
// result
select * from students where name='john' and age='23';
```